# Language keeps returning to the default settings in Linux Xfce

Tags: linux, layout, keyboard, xfce

I am using the Linux Xfce machine provided for us by our professor which has Turkish keyboard layout. Every time I change the language, it changes for a while and then return back to the Turkish layout again, even if I remove the Turkish layout form the system!!
[image]

Is there any way to solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared after running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install x11-xkb-utils
setxkbmap us
echo "setxkbmap us" >> ~/.bashrc
```

I found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/404457/how-can-i-change-the-input-keyboard-layout-while-in-the-console/973296#973296?newreg=037a8ac45cb54d0c99c9d63c85588df7)